# Problem installing NVIDIA driver - AntiX

Tags: linux, nvidia, password, root, antix

Goodnight!

I cannot install the **NVIDIA driver**. It asks for the **root password**, but it won't let me type it. As far as I know the password would be "demo".

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are trying to do.